# Inherited Form.Text - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Custom Class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, inheritance

So I'm working with form inheritance and I'm overriding the .Text() property of the base form.  Everything works great with the inheritance except when I attempt to call a custom class property.

```
public partial class baseForm : Form
{
    public baseForm() { InitializeComponent(); }
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value + " - " + customClass.employee.userId;
        }
    }
}
```

When I enable my code of customClass.employee.userId by designer of the derived class breaks and I receive an error message of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  My code compiles without errors and during run, even executes correctly as planned.  The results are there, but I need the designer.

How do I have the designer back without having to comment out this line all the time while in development, then uncomment it for production?

**EDIT**
The customClass in instantiated in a login form at runtime for the entire app.  During my login, in frmLogin.cs, upon successful login, I set the object of the class.

```
customClass.employee = new customClass.clsEMPLOYEEModel(connectionString, userId.Text);


public static class customClass
{
    public static clsDynamicClass.clsEMPLOYEEModel employee
    {
        get
        {
            return _employee;
        }
        set
        {
            _employee = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the `Text` property is used by the designer, and it doesn't have your instance of `customClass`.  Where do you define that instance?

Comment: where is your customClass instatiate? please insert your customClass code

Comment: The designer of your `baseForm` will not look at your overridden `Text`  property. Do you get exception in designer of forms inherited from `baseForm`?

Answer (score 0):

> The customClass in instantiated in a login form at runtime for the entire app

That means that the `employee` property is not set as design-time.  I would suggest either initializing `employee` with a "dummy" value in the constructor, or checking for `null` in the setter:

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        return base.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        if(customClass != null && customClass.employee != null)
            base.Text = value + " - " + customClass.employee.userId;
        else
            base.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: D Stanley - This was the solution to the question I had.  Thanks!